# How to subclass Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Route?

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

In Phalcon 1.3 I can return `My\Mvc\Router` that extends `Phalcon\Mvc\Router`.

Question: how can I swap in a custom matched route of `My\Mvc\Router\Route` type ?

Thanks!

Comment: my question is... why to? Actual routing system in Phalcon is quite advanced, naver had do change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a route in `My\Mvc\Router` it will overwrite `Phalcon\Mvc\Router` as one extends the other.